# Can I know which site collection an App Permission was registered at (_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, pnp-powershell, pnp

I have many App Permissions which are showing inside my App Permission page, as below:-

[image]

and as seen here:-

[image]

**but is there a way to know the site/s where this app was registered at using the _layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx? page** I need this because I want to remove unwanted App Permissions (from the app catalog) which were created for testing and to delete those app permissions from the app catalog I need to first uninstall them from the related site collection/s.

Thanks in advance for any help.
Regards

Comment: You should be able to loop through your sites and check for the app using Get-PnPApp - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpapp?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: @Christoffer thanks for the reply is there a sample code i can follow?

Comment: Something like this might work. Replace it with your tenant URL and the app identity you are looking for.

Comment: $cred = Get-Credential

Connect-PnPOnline "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com" -Credentials $cred
$sites = Get-PnPTenantSite
foreach ($site in $sites)
{
   Connect-PnPOnline -Url $site.Url -Credentials $cred
   Get-PnPApp -Scope Site -Identity 2646ccc3-6a2b-46ef-9273-81411cbbb60f
}

Comment: @Christoffer thanks for the code sample,, but how i can know if the app is found inside the site collection,, seems your code will just loop through all sites.. is this correct? or i am missing something ?

Comment: Correct, I did not provide a fully functional script - It need's some tweaking to suit your needs. Connect manually to a site that you know does not have the app, run get-pnpApp and compare the result from a site where the app exists and take it from there.

Comment: @Christoffer i did not get your point